# How to find text in a column with Python

Tags: python, parsing, text, split, find

If I had the text below in a variable, what is the best way to be able to search with say `"NetName:"` and get `"LVLT-GOGL-8-8-8"` returned?

```
NetRange:       8.8.8.0 - 8.8.8.255

CIDR:           8.8.8.0/24

NetName:        LVLT-GOGL-8-8-8

NetHandle:      NET-8-8-8-0-1

Parent:         LVLT-ORG-8-8 (NET-8-0-0-0-1)

NetType:        Reallocated

NetType:        Reallocated

OriginAS:  

Organization:   Google Inc. (GOGL)

RegDate:        2014-03-14

Updated:        2014-03-14

Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-8-8-8-0-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex,in this case [*re.search*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) could does the job :

```
>>> s="""NetRange:       8.8.8.0 - 8.8.8.255
... 
... CIDR:           8.8.8.0/24
... 
... NetName:        LVLT-GOGL-8-8-8
... 
... NetHandle:      NET-8-8-8-0-1
... 
... Parent:         LVLT-ORG-8-8 (NET-8-0-0-0-1)
... 
... NetType:        Reallocated
... 
... NetType:        Reallocated
... 
... OriginAS:  
... 
... Organization:   Google Inc. (GOGL)
... 
... RegDate:        2014-03-14
... 
... Updated:        2014-03-14
... 
... Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-8-8-8-0-1"""
>>> import re

>>> re.search(r'NetName:\s+(.*)',s).group(1)
'LVLT-GOGL-8-8-8'
```

Or you can loop over the splitted string and use a generator expression :

```
>>> next(line.split()[-1] for line in s.split('\n') if 'NetName:' in line)
'LVLT-GOGL-8-8-8'
```

Comment: @gamarga welcome! so what about accepting the answer? ;)

Comment: Done! (I had to google how to accept answers, newbie in the house eh?!)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

ff = """NetRange:       8.8.8.0 - 8.8.8.255

CIDR:           8.8.8.0/24

NetName:        LVLT-GOGL-8-8-8

NetHandle:      NET-8-8-8-0-1

Parent:         LVLT-ORG-8-8 (NET-8-0-0-0-1)

NetType:        Reallocated

NetType:        Reallocated

OriginAS:  

Organization:   Google Inc. (GOGL)

RegDate:        2014-03-14

Updated:        2014-03-14

Ref:            http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-8-8-8-0-1"""


m = re.search("NetRange:(.*)\n", ff)
print m.groups() # or do
print m.group(1)
```